Allow CallbackQueryHandler only for command sender
The user sends some /command to the bot, and the bot responds to it with some message with InlineKeyboardMarkup. But every user in the chat can interact with that InlineKeyboardMarkup
...
async def command(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    keyboard = [[InlineKeyboardButton('Click me!')]]
    markup = InlineKeyboardMarkup(keyboard)
    
    await update.message.reply_text(text='Click on button!', reply_markup=markup)


async def hello(update: Update, context: ContextTypes.DEFAULT_TYPE) -> None:
    query = update.callback_query
    await query.answer()
    
    await query.edit_message_text('Hello!')
...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ...
    application.add_handler(CommandHandler('command', command))
    application.add_handler(CallbackQueryHandler(hello))
    ...

I need to avoid it, so the bot will ignore clicks on keyboard from other users.
I tried to store command sender and message ID in application.chat_data, so I can check if the user allowed to interact with a certain keyboard, but maybe there are some built-in ways to realize it in telegram.ext, or maybe you know a better way to implement it.
